# Substring of a line from a file is not working for one specific line in Java

Tags: java

Before I start I know this isnt the only way of getting the information from the file I need, since I can use a scanner. However when i've been trying to read it this way the substring seems to be causing problems with this line from the Contract.txt file:07-Jun-2016 1   3   1   N   JB847N  900 S Trotter

Which thorws a NormatFormatException "00    " because it is trying to then parse a tab. This is the only line that does this.

---

```
public String averageCostOflarge() {
    int numberOfBundles = 0;
    int total = 0;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Contract.txt"));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.charAt(14) == '3') {
                numberOfBundles++;
                if(line.charAt(32)=='\t'){
                    total+=Integer.parseInt(line.substring(28, 32));
                }else{
                    total+=Integer.parseInt(line.substring(28, 31));
                }
            }

        }
        reader.close();
        return Integer.toString(numberOfBundles);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return "Error";
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ContractSummary.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

However the it seems to mainly be this part: 1  3   1   N   JB847N  900 as this part comes up multiple times in the file.

Contract file: https://pastebin.com/GFG1Um4g

---

I have removed all the lines that have been causing this problem and the code works just fine.

The section of code needs to check if the third row is set as 3 and then get the cost in the seventh row. The pieces of information are seperated by tabs not spaces and I have tried manually typing the line that is causing the problem to see if it was a formatting error in the file.

Any explanation as to why my code is doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you maybe post a picture where we can clearly see the line error occurs on and the Exception text, it's obvious that somewhere you're trying to pass non-digit string to an integer.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/y2oRC Error is specifically line 73 when trying to convert and is happening becuase of the tab, but the problem is the code works fine apart from that line in the file

Comment: If the Contract.txt is what you posted on pastebin, I can't see where this line will evaluate to true: if (line.charAt(14) == '3') as character at index 14 is always a space character and never '3'.

Comment: Please post a picture of ContractManager.java class where I can clearly see line 15.

Comment: The tabs count as characters which make the character at 14 become the third row

Comment: And ContractManager is just main https://imgur.com/a/D0TR6

Comment: Sorry I couldn't make a distinction between \t and any number of  \s chars.

Comment: In your while loop before you do any of the checks, can you real quick make a for loop and iterate over each character in line string and print it along with it's index and let me know the results.

Comment: You could try using a text editor and replace all tabs with pipes so that they are visible. That way you can revisit your logic with something you can clearly see. Then you can switch back to tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with a tab; your substring is either "00 " or "00 S", depending on whether the letter following the S is a tab.  But parseInt("00 ") throws an exception because of the trailing space.

If you are trying to extract the "900", then your index is off; the first index should be 27 instead of 28.  And if you only want to get the part of "900" after the 9, then only ask for 2characters, substring(28,30).

However, depending on the exact character-index seems rather brittle -- sure the date will be a predictable number of characters long, but are the following "1 3 1" each *guaranteed* to be a single digit, and never longer?  Similarly, the "N" and "JB847N" aren't ever longer/shorter?
My first inclination would be to use String.split("\s") to divide your long line into the meaningful chunks.

(Btw, you are looking for the 3rd and 7th "columns" (or, "fields"), not "rows".)

Comment: The first index of 28 works for every other line in the Contract file apart from this one. If I change it to 27 then it stops working for the others picking up the tab on the lefthand side. I also know there are a lot of better ways then doing it then how I have done above its more just about what is causing that specific line to stop it working

Comment: @Kirky373 then every other line of the file is a slightly longer than this one, maybe?  Counting the characters in what you provide (starting from index 0), index 28 is the first '0' in "900".

Comment: I thought that to begin with but all the costs begin at the same index

Comment: Nevermind the index as you said is shorter because of the fouth column, thanks for youre help youve saved me kicking myself over it haha

Answer (score 0):

You need to added `trim()` to remove spaces

```
if (line.charAt(32) == '\t') {
    total += Integer.parseInt(line.substring(28, 32).trim());
} else {
    total += Integer.parseInt(line.substring(28, 31).trim());
}
```